# What would an adjective to an adjective be called?

Tags: adjectives, sentence, compound-adjectives

In the sentence "The very fast dog ran outside.", the words are `article (adjective?) adjective noun verb adverb`.

Would it be correct to say "very" in that sentence is also an adjective word? Or would that not count as an adjective, since "very" is not an attribute to "dog" but to "fast"?

Comment: 'Very', like 'extremely' etc, is  traditionally classed as an adverb in its intensifier role. There are those who think that different POSs, 'secondary modifier [of adjective]' and  'secondary modifier [of adverb]'  are more justifiable for words fulfilling these roles (but catchier names would be an advantage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Very** is only an adjective when it modifies a noun, as in "Those were my very words" or "Let's start from the very beginning."

In all other cases, it is an adverb.